# whats the meaning of this sytax in VB "If(a & b)"

Tags: c#, vb.net, if-statement, translate

I'm trying to translate a certain code to c#.

Basically I understand most of the code I'm dealing with, and even the intent of the original code.
but I wanna be sure I have all my bases covered.

its the 5th post in this topic: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-to-use-getwindowlong-properly-in-vb-net.1312789/
by user Kresimir

the code at question:

```
Dim ret As Integer = User32DLL.GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -16)
Dim s As String = String.Empty
If (ret And WS_BORDER) Then s &= "WS_BORDER" & NewLine
```

I do not understand what the "If (ret And WS_BORDER)" statement is supposed to do, and how to translate it to C#

is it:

```
    if (ret!=null & WS_BORDER!=null)
```

or something else?

Thank you.

edit: note. If I use the above mentioned C# statement, VS gives me a notice that "the result of the expression is always false since a value of type "int" is never equal to "null" of type "int?"
^I guess I can neglect it(googling it as we speak), but if sm1 wishes to give me a "free of charge explanation" I'd appreciate it :*

ps. I'm really a newb to this, so I'm sorry if I overlooked something obvious.

Comment: It's a bit-wise and

Comment: operator & can not be applied to operands of type "int" and "bool"
Tried it with "ret & WS_BORDER != null" as well.

Comment: Apologies, the parenthesis are important there. Missed that. See Gusman's answer.

Comment: Well, to be clear, it's always two operations. My error was just a matter of `!=` having a higher precedence than `&`, which I wasn't thinking about.

Comment: [VB.Net - And Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx) seem to explain what is going on pretty well. Could you please clarify what you did not get out of the MSDN article?

Comment: To learn more, read [Bitwise Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx#Anchor_3)

Comment: One more tip: if you want to find information - use search engine... I.e. to fine equivalent of statement in one language try "c# equivalent of vb.net and", you may want to try multiple search engines like one provided by company I work for: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+equivalent+of+vb.net+and

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate to me. The question isn't about what "and" means, it's about what it means in the context of an integer.

Comment: Alexei, thank you for your comment. I did try. But Im new to programming and at this stage its merely a hobby. I'm trying to hack things that are above my level. I understand the concepts of operators, but as Gendolkari stated, I had trouble converting the code from VB to C#, and did not want to overlook something. As stated, I have tried different methods, which are "in the ballpark" but did not work. 
I'm thankfull for your links.  attm I'm struggling with a steep learning curve... I'm looking for suited learning path, and or resources are "dumbed down" enough for my lvl. Pls recommend more

Answer (score 6):

None of the previous answers are right:

```
if((ret & WS_BORDER) != 0)
```

This is a check to see if a variable contains a flag, in this case WS_BORDER.

Comment: wow! Thank you! it works. 
I've been breaking my balls over this for the 2 days now. (was a bit shy to post here... this is my first post ever on stackoverflow) 
TY GUYS!!! 
This was more than I hoped for! 10 minutes problem solved!!! LOVE IT!
virtual beer to all of ya!

Answer (score -1):

This is a bitwise logic operation. When Visual Basic converts numeric data type values to Boolean, 0 becomes False and all other values become True. So if the statement is not 0:

`User32DLL.GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -16)`

...and WS_BORDER is not falsy the result will be true. If either are false, the result will be false.